# PHPOffice write a new file fatal errors

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I am using [this](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to create `.xlsx` files from my `PHP` script.

Following [this](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/) guide, I've tried exporting some data to a file called `hello.xlsx`.

However, this errors with the below messages:

> Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception: Could not close zip file hello.xlsx. in vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php on line 399
>
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception: Could not close zip file hello.xlsx. in /vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php on line 399

The file doesn't exist pre-execution so I kind of get the errors. I could always try to `touch hello.xlsx` and change my script to read that file and append the data, but really, I'm trying to write a new file each time the script is run.

Here is my (simplified) code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'foo');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'bar');
$sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'foobar');
$sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'trey is the best');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello.xlsx');
```

Going to those lines in the error show this snippet o' code:

```
// Close file
if ($zip->close() === false) {
    throw new WriterException("Could not close zip file $pFilename.");
}
```

To me, that isn't exactly a helpful message to debug what's going wrong.

I've found various SO posts on this:

- [PHPExcel_Writer_Exception with message Could not close zip file php://output.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436949/phpexcel-writer-exception-with-message-could-not-close-zip-file-php-output)

The accepted answer unfortunately didn't work (changed code to `$writer->save($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/hello.xlsx')`).

I also tried the `SaveFiaTempFile` function but that just outputs a bunch of funny characters.

I also don't want to set my folder/file permissions to 777 as that's insane in the membrane.

- [PHPExcel exception: Could not close zip file …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068419/phpexcel-exception-could-not-close-zip-file)

This accepted answer doesn't really suggest what the correct thing to do is IMO other than change ownerships, but .. change what to what?

So how do I go about fixing/debugging the issue without much to really go on?

Thanks :)

**UPDATE**

So I thought I'd double check something, I made a folder in my project_root called `tmp`. I changed my code to write to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/tmp/hello.xlsx'` and it still gave out the errors.

However, I thought "*Hey, let's just open it for jokes*" and to my surprise the data is all there, everything seems OK.. but for whatever reason, it still gets the error instead of coming up with the download popup in my browser ..

Comment: **www-data** is the user that some web servers use by default for normal operation. It needs to have permissions to write in the folder.

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue to me!

Comment: @abn yee I know, I just mean, what folder, the file is not in any folder so to speak

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think you're right, but I'm not sure where to target? haha

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50476471/3340665

Comment: Trey: Try giving the `$writer->save('hello.xlsx');` a path to somewhere you know should be writable.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I actually found a better solution! forgot all about this question, will post now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution to create dynamic Xlsx files:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="hello.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Here, we literally just redirect the browser to the `php://output` and download the file.